# How to get people interests from Google +?

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-domain-api, google-plus-domains

I am trying to get user profile information such as people in circles, interest, feeds, plusoners and reshares.

I tried during a lot of time and it was imposible to me getting **interest and people in circles**.

In Google Domains API there is a way to get all people from circles but even with OAuth shows this error:

```
"error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "forbidden",
            "message": "Forbidden"
        }
    ],
        "code": 403,
            "message": "Forbidden"
}
```

I think that the poblem is that Google only provides this information if you are a G Suite user, not a Google 'normal' user.

About the interest, I have no idea.

Anyone knows how to get this info (*interests and people in circles*) from Google Plus API?

Sorry for my english :(

Answer (score 0):

[Google domains api](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/) is not the [Google+ api](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/).

The Domains API is for use with a GSuite account. Google+ API.

```
"error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "forbidden",
            "message": "Forbidden"
        }
    ],
        "code": 403,
            "message": "Forbidden"
}
```

Means that you are trying to use the domains api but do not have access to a gsuite account.

You can try and use the [people api](https://developers.google.com/people/) which will give you a list of who the user has emailed and who they have in their contacts.  I dont think it has anything to do with who they have in their circles to my knowledge there is no way to retrieve that information.

Comment: So Google only allows to get interest and circles info if you have a G Suite account? That doesn´t make much sense, does it?

Comment: Does it have to make sense?  but it is a feature request https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-plus-platform/issues/1218